# Sending props to a map callback outside the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working with React. I have a class with a **state** with an **array**. The list array, I can make a .map to iterate over it.

```
 {this.state.list.map((e, i) => {/*do your stuffs*/}
```

Now, I want to send the logic outside my map, the reason, I have another component that should render the same content but with a different array.

The problem, I am calling methods from the class. So, my question is, how can I create a function outside my class that access into my class methods??

This is what I have so far:

```
  {this.state.list.map(mapping)}
```

And the mapping function:

```
const mapping = (e, i) =>  {
  return (  
    <div className='form-row' key={i}>
      <SelectInput 
        uid={i}
        data = {e.red.toString()}
        handleChange = {this.handleChange}
        options = {this.props.options}
        label = {'Red Social'}  col = {'col-md-5'}
        name = {'red'} />
        (...)
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined

I want the handle change method to be relative to the current class. In one class I have to modify a specific state with a specific function, in other, well other function do other things.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can show the whole component definition. 

Comment: Add `SelectInput` component code to your question

Comment: Is a class component, with a state definition and methods to generate more elements for my `list` array from the state. It also updates the redux store in the onChange method. I think it is a more a general question about *how to create global methods for being reusable in other components* @PraveenKumarPurushothaman @lankovova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) accepts an optional `thisArg` as the second parameter:

> Value to use as `this` when executing `callback`.

Call your `mapping` function like this:

```js
this.state.list.map(mapping, this)
```

...and `mapping` will be called with your component as `this`.

---

Then change your `mapping` function to a *standard function* instead of an *arrow function* so it doesn't automatically capture ["the `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

```js
const mapping = function (e, i) {  // <= normal function
  return (  
    <div className='form-row' key={i}>
      <SelectInput 
        uid={i}
        data = {e.red.toString()}
        handleChange = {this.handleChange}  // <= 'this' is your component
        options = {this.props.options}
        label = {'Red Social'}  col = {'col-md-5'}
        name = {'red'} />
        (...)
```

...and `this` will refer to your component within `mapping`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just have one doubt more. How to handle mapping has a class component?

Answer (score 1):

That two classes should use the same piece of code that relies on their properties means that classes should inherit from base class, and common method should be bound to the context:

```
class Base extends Component {
  mapping = this.mapping.bind(this);
  mapping(e, i) { ... }
}

class Foo extends Base {
  render() {
    ...
    {this.state.list.map(this.mapping)}
    ...
  }
}
```

React officially promotes [composition instead of inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) for such cases. Reusable functionality should be extracted to separate component that accepts common parameters as props:

```
const SelectInputList = ({ list, handleChange, options }) => {
  return list.map((e, i) => (
    <div className='form-row' key={i}>
      <SelectInput 
        uid={i}
        data = {e.red.toString()}
        handleChange = {handleChange}]
        options = {options}
        ...
});
```

Comment: I would like the composition method, but in my case, the selectInput is used in other components, not with that params. I will not send them always a List Array. Should I create a middle component? like a `mappingFields` that receive an array and `inputComponent`and generate this (loop)? If that is the recommendation, can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you correctly. That you have SelectInputList doesn't mean that you can't use SelectInput in other places if you need it. I updated the question with how it's supposed to be used. Do you mean that SelectInput doesn't refer to specific component but is dynamic? Can you update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains the problem with SelectInput?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I thought that your `SelectInputList` was my `SelectInput` and you were proposing me to refactor that. But I get what you say now, in fact, this is what I really wanted, I wanted to have a component in the middle,  that handle the `List`array. I get it now, thanks!